# Cache behavior in Tomasulo algorithm

Tags: algorithm, caching, cpu-architecture

Trying to implement Tomasulo, I have a fully associative cache (32 byte) with 16 byte block size. The cache is currently filled with a0, a1 (16b each) and LRU is a0. I am using branch prediction, starting to load a2  in the cache but the load stage is not completed because my prediction was false. The new instruction suggests that I should load a0. Is it going to be a hit or a miss?

I don't understand when the cache contents are renewed, does the execute stage of the pipeline in the load instruction have to be complete?

Comment: Isn't the phrase "fully associative direct mapped" self contradictory?

Comment: Yes sorry, it's not direct mapped..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then it's not something the algorithm defines.

It really a matter of the specific implementation that you choose, and if you allow speculative execution (or how fast you can flush your pipeline).

If for example, you allow deep speculative execution, then it means that the LOAD may be executed, so the cache can be polluted with a2.

One the other hand, if you do not allow speculative execution, and you wait for the branch to be resolved (in the execute stage), or you correct your pipeline fast enough, then you can prevent from the LOAD to take place and prevent the eviction of a0.

So basically it really up to the chosen implementation.
The execution stage of the load instruction itself does not directly affect whether it's a hit or a miss in the cache, but the timing and order of events in the pipeline do matter.